# while loop for condition_variable

Tags: c++

In the following example, I don't understand the purpose of `ready`. What is difference with or without using `ready` in this example?

```
#include <iostream>           // std::cout
#include <thread>             // std::thread
#include <mutex>              // std::mutex, std::unique_lock
#include <condition_variable> // std::condition_variable

std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cv;
bool ready = false;

void print_id (int id) {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  while (!ready) cv.wait(lck);
  // ...
  std::cout << "thread " << id << '\n';
}

void go() {
  std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(mtx);
  ready = true;
  cv.notify_all();
}

int main ()
{
  std::thread threads[10];
  // spawn 10 threads:
  for (int i=0; i<10; ++i)
    threads[i] = std::thread(print_id,i);

  std::cout << "10 threads ready to race...\n";
  go();                       // go!

  for (auto& th : threads) th.join();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: the `condition_variable` could, for one reason or another, kick out early and it the program's not `ready`... Better to make sure. Testing a flag is less destructive than [nuking the entire site from orbit](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhfPyreR_sE).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is that `cv.wait(lck);` can return *before* the `notify_all` call has been made, due to things called "spurious wakeups". You can see [Spurious wakeups explanation sounds like a bug that just isn't worth fixing, is that right?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/186842/spurious-wakeups-explanation-sounds-like-a-bug-that-just-isnt-worth-fixing-is) for some more information about the reasons for this.

Thus, the waiting/notifying threads use an additional predicate (`ready` in this case) to signal whether the condition was signaled or whether the condition awoke due to a spurious wakeup.

Answer (score -1):

When it is not `ready`(`ready` is false) you will block thread/threads until you will call one/all of them and let them do their job. However when `ready` is true, you will not block any threads. It is important, because without `ready` flag you might block thread which should be executing and therefore there will be no information to let it run again(when you block thread you have to notify it, otherwise it will wait forever)